# Google Adsense Alternatives after google Account Disabled

Tags: admob, adsense

Google has closed my Adsense account - the reason is invalid transactions were made to my account.

I have no idea what i did wrong - because I did not violate any laws they defined.

I went into their forum and realized that I was not the only one to close the account for no real reason.

I developed application and published them on Google Play - and I added to them ad.

I started looking for [alternatives](https://stream-seo.com/best-google-adsense-alternatives/) to Google Adsense - and I saw that there are several possibilities.

My question is, does anyone know from personal experience these alternatives?

Comment: Any solution here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you believe you did nothing wrong, didn't click your own ads or violate any of [their policies](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2753860?hl=en), then you should [appeal](https://support.google.com/admob/contact/appeal_account_disable)

Regarding alternatives, from experience the [Facebook Audience Network](https://developers.facebook.com/products/audience-network/overview/) (FAN) seems to be a better alternative, in fact you can earn more from FAN than with admob, however there's an issue of low fill rate as users must have the Facebook app installed on their devices. You can use other networks as fallback when there's no ad to serve

Also note that FAN is strict with its policies so make sure there isn't a repeat of whatever caused the deactivation of your adsense account.

Comment: I tried to appeal but it took them exactly 5 minutes after I sent them the appeal to give me an answer that the appeal was denied and that they are not changing their decision.
To use FAN(Facebook) you need to have facebook account - and in my case i don't have ( and will not have in the future ). 

Is someone know from personal experience other alternatives ?

Comment: Can't you create a fb account for business purposes? There are other ad networks like the alternatives you posted but I can't talk about them as I haven't used them before. I've used startapp and airpush but these days those networks aren't performing well

Comment: It is a matter of principle that the subject of creating an account on Facebook. I will not have an account there even not a fake account for advertising